# Getting Tab sessionStorage from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the sessionStorage from the current tab and am not able to.

I have the following code:

```
  function getSessionStorage() {
    var script = 'window.sessionStorage';

    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: script
    }, function(results){
        console.log(results); // produces [{}] instead of sessionStorage
    });
  }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: That's how it works. Only a snapshot of the object is passed, internally it's JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

Comment: @wOxxOm so if I JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)) the results I should get the full?

Comment: @wOxxOm I just tried, and no luck. still [{}]

Comment: What? My comment means you can't pass a direct reference to sessionStorage.

Comment: @wOxxOm YES - thanks! changing the line to `var script = 'JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.sessionStorage))';` seems to have worked. Thanks!

If you set it as an answer, I'm happy to select it.